# R Calculate a function by groups and on many variables

Tags: r, plyr, apply

I have a large data-set with many variables, and would like to some calculations on all of them, by factors and have the results returned in a nice-looking data-frame. So, my data could look like this:

Data-example:

```
df <- data.frame( 
  hour    = factor(rep(1:24, each = 100)),
  price   = runif(20)*100,
  cons = sample(1:100,2400, replace = T),
  wind = sample(1:100,2400, replace = T),
  solar = sample(1:100,2400, replace = T)
)
```

I would like to run some simple calculations on each variable - by factors - with a function like this:

```
fx <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  mean <- mean(x)
  median <- median(x)
  std <- sd(x)
  var <- var(x)
  max <- max(x)
  min <- min(x)

#results <-list(n, mean, median, std, var, max, min)
#return(results)

}
```

It would be great to get them out in a data-frame like this:

```
datasummary: 
hour(factor)   length(price)   mean(price)   ...   min(price)   length(cons)   ...   etc
1         
2
3
..
24
```

Now this works fine, if I do it manually for each variable, but I guess there must be an easier way to do this with plyr or an apply trick. But I cant figure out how to go from a single variable to a whole data-frame, nor how I can get it back into a data-frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using R base function `aggregate`

```
set.seed(1)  # your data, set.seed(1) is for reproducibility
df <- data.frame( 
  hour    = factor(rep(1:24, each = 100)),
  price   = runif(20)*100,
  cons = sample(1:100,2400, replace = T),
  wind = sample(1:100,2400, replace = T),
  solar = sample(1:100,2400, replace = T)
)

# a slightly modified version of your function
 fx <- function(x) {
  c(n=length(x), mean=mean(x), median=quantile(x, .5),
    std=sd(x), var=var(x), max=max(x), min=min(x))  
}

# applying your function and getting results
> agresult <- aggregate(.~hour, FUN=fx, data=df)
> agresult <- do.call(data.frame, agresult)
> agresult[1:6,1:8]


 hour price.n price.mean price.median.50. price.std price.var price.max price.min
1    1     100   55.51671         60.09837  28.02782  785.5584  99.19061  6.178627
2    2     100   55.51671         60.09837  28.02782  785.5584  99.19061  6.178627
3    3     100   55.51671         60.09837  28.02782  785.5584  99.19061  6.178627
4    4     100   55.51671         60.09837  28.02782  785.5584  99.19061  6.178627
5    5     100   55.51671         60.09837  28.02782  785.5584  99.19061  6.178627
6    6     100   55.51671         60.09837  28.02782  785.5584  99.19061  6.178627
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It's called the `numcolwise` argument to `ddply`...

```
require( plyr)
ddply( df , .(hour) , numcolwise( mean ) )
#   hour   price  cons  wind solar
#1     1 58.0735 55.21 47.42 48.10
#2     2 58.0735 53.50 47.36 48.91
#3     3 58.0735 52.10 50.13 48.56
#4     4 58.0735 49.78 46.17 53.33
#5     5 58.0735 49.46 50.40 49.29
#6     6 58.0735 49.59 55.66 50.27
```

Or using `reshape2::dcast`...

```
require( reshape2 )
dcast( melt( df , id = "hour" ) , formula = hour ~ variable , mean )
```

Comment: Can you include more calculations than mean in this example? As far as I can see I then need to do 7 plyr calculations (if I want 7 different calculations).

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a way to do it, but that would be a nice feature to have, e.g. ddply( df , .(hour) , summarise , mean(...) , sd(...) , median(...) )` with `...` meaning all the variables not being used to split up the `data.frame` (as it is in the casting formula).